# How to configure pxelinux.cfg/default properly in order to install Ubuntu from network?

Tags: boot, pxe

I'm trying to set up PXE in order to install Ubuntu 13.10 Server x64 through local network. So far, I can boot through PXE and, when using `pxelinux.cfg/default` provided by default, be able to install Ubuntu by downloading it from a mirror.

I want to be able to install Ubuntu from NFS. I edited `pxelinux.cfg/default` like this:

```
1  # D-I config version 2.0
2  default ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/vesamenu.c32
3  menu title Ubuntu setup
4  label ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64
5          menu label ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64
6          kernel 3.11.0.18-generic
7          append netboot=nfs initrd=install/initrd.gz nfsroot=192.168.1.75:/↵
   exports/ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64 ip=dhcp rw
```

- 192.168.1.75 is the IP of the server I use for DHCP, DNS and NFS,
- I got the kernel `3.11.0.18-generic` by running `uname -r`,
- `showmount -e 192.168.1.75` gives:

  > `Export list for 192.168.1.75:`
  >   `/exports/ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64 192.168.1.0/24`

  The directory contains the contents of the original ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64 image.

When booting from PXE, I get the original screen (see screenshots below), then another one. Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> shows the command:

> `3.11.0.18-generic netboot=nfs initrd=install/initrd.gz nfsroot=192.168.1.↵`
>   `75:/exports/ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64 ip=dhcp rw`

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> does nothing.

I imagine there is something wrong with my changes of `pxelinux.cfg/default`.

What's wrong with it?

Is there a comprehensive documentation of the options to set?

Are there logs which can help understanding what is wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Consider using Alt+F1, Alt+F2, .... Alt+F7 to view any available tty consoles. On a centos pxe install that works, I'm guessing it's a pxelinux feature that you can also use here to slightly debug what's happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your kernel and init are not loading (hence the hang). Are you sure your paths are correct? Also, check your filenames -- I'm not sure where you got 3.11.0.18-generic, my 14.04 server DVD netboot kernel is a file called "linux".

This line:

```
6          kernel 3.11.0.18-generic
```

Implies that a file called `3.11.0.18-generic` exists in the root of your TFTP server, e.g. something like `\tftpboot\3.11.0.18-generic` or `\var\lib\tftp\3.11.0.18-generic`. Let's call this TFTPROOT. Similarly for `install/initrd.gz` - is there a file `TFTPROOT/install/initrd.gz`?

Your path on line 2 (`default ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/vesamenu.c32`) implies that you've copied the contents of DVDISO/install/netboot into your TFTP server root. E.g. you've likely got a folder called `TFTPROOT/ubuntu-installer`. However, the proper kernel and init file for netboot are(for me) contained in DVDISO/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64. So your paths should be `kernel ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux` and `append initrd=ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz ...`

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem, and could hit enter after changing file permission for kernel and inird.

Try with setting `chmod 777 3.11.0.18-generic`