# LTSP on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ltsp

I am trying to install LTSP on Ubuntu 17.04
Have used ltsp-server and dnsmasq as dhcp proxy.
Sailed through installation.

Was able to create chroot i386.

However, when testing client i receive messages like

```
/dev/nbd0 is not present. dropping to shell
Nbdserver status has a message "unable to export....."
```

I need your help with this issue.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

take a look on [How to configure pxelinux.cfg/default properly in order to install Ubuntu from network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445653/how-to-configure-pxelinux-cfg-default-properly-in-order-to-install-ubuntu-from-n)

After change "NBD boot"  for "NFS boot" in pxelinux.cfg/default/ltsp ,  it works for me.

**1. Install nfs-kernel-server**

```
 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-16-04
```

**2. Add follow line in /etc/exports:**

```
 /opt/ltsp/i386/ 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0(ro,no_root_squash)
```

Note: Change 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 by your Network addr

**3. Change update-kernels.conf and run "sudo service ltsp-update-kernels"** ( the pxe files are regenerated)

On the file /etc/ltsp/update-kernels.conf , change the line BOOT_METHODS for

```
BOOT_METHODS="NFS"
```

and the line TIMEOUT for

```
TIMEOUT=120
```

**4. Configure pxe files**

On the /var/liv/tftpboot/ltsp/i386/pxelinux.cfg/ltsp

**a)change line "default ltsp-NBD"**

```
default ltsp-NFS
```

**b) on the section "label ltsp-NFS"**

change string "boot=nbd" for 
   boot=nfs 
change the string "root=/dev/nbd0" for "root=/dev/nfs"

and add at the end of line :

```
nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/opt/ltsp/i386
```

(Note: change 192.168.0.1 by your server IP addr )

Ref [How to configure pxelinux.cfg/default properly in order to install Ubuntu from network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445653/how-to-configure-pxelinux-cfg-default-properly-in-order-to-install-ubuntu-from-n)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to [edit] to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference as if digitalocean.com goes down step one is lost. Thank you!